# Accessing Views from couchdb module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, couchdb, cloudant

-

While working with views in [couchdb-python](https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/) module, I noticed that python loads the whole result set in memory before it starts processing it. So even if you specify a limit and skip parameter, it will first load the whole result set in memory, then apply the limit, skip restrictions and finally come back with results.

For example, here's my code :

```
import requests
import json
import couchdb
import time

couch = couchdb.Server(url)

def dumpidtofile(dbname,view):
    db=couch[dbname]
    func_total_time=0
    count=db.info()['doc_count'] # Get a count of total number of documents
    batch=count // 10000 # Divide the total count in batches of 10000 and save the quotient 
    f=open(dbname, 'w')
    if batch == 0 :
        print ("Number of documents less that 10000. continuing !!")
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        for item in db.view(view):
            # print (item.key)
            f.write(item.key)
            f.write('\n')
        elapsed_time = time.monotonic() - start_time
        func_total_time=elapsed_time
        print ("Loop finished. Time spent in this loop was {0}".format(elapsed_time))
        print ("Total Function Time :", func_total_time)
    else:
        print ("Number of documents greater that 10000. Breaking into batches !!")
        batch=batch + 1 # This is the number of times that we would have to iterate to retrieve all documents
        for i in range(batch):
            start_time = time.monotonic()
            for item in db.view(view,limit=10000,skip=i*10000):
                # print (item.key)
                f.write(item.key)
                f.write('\n')
            elapsed_time = time.monotonic() - start_time
            func_total_time = func_total_time + elapsed_time
            print ("Loop {0} finished. Time spent in this loop was {1}".format(i,elapsed_time))
        print ("Total Function Time :", func_total_time)
    f.close()

prog_start_time = time.monotonic()
dumpidtofile("mydb","myindex/myview")
prog_end_time = time.monotonic() - prog_start_time
print ("Total Program Time :", prog_end_time)
```

And here's my sample output.

[image]

The program waited a good ~90 secs at the point highlighted in image before proceeding. That's when I suspected that the view was probably getting loaded in entirety before it even start processing those loops. Now this might be fine for small databases, but dosen't seem that great for large databases (some of the database I work with are ~15/20 gbs)

Hence I guess my question is :

1. Is there a better way to iterate over documents, esp in larges databases, by just loading a portion of them at a time.
2. How do I figure out where is the most time spent in this program and how do I optimize it ?

Apologies the length of the question. I dint realize it got that long while  typing. :)

Thanks -A

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [python-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant) library. It can fetch results in batches.

Example:

```
from cloudant import couchdb_admin_party
from cloudant.result import Result

db_name = 'animaldb'
ddoc_id = 'views101'
view_id = 'diet'

with couchdb_admin_party(url='http://localhost:5984') as client:
    db = client.get(db_name, remote=True)
    view = db.get_design_document(ddoc_id).get_view(view_id)

    with open('/tmp/results.txt', 'w') as f:
        for result in Result(view, page_size=1000):
            f.write(result.get('key') + '\n')
```